# Android Libgdx LiveWallpaper does not stop

Tags: android, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I am creating an Android Live Wallpaper with Libgdx , It is just a circle on the screen which gets a random color and position and it slowly moves up .

The issue is after setting the live wallpaper , when I again click on the app icon , instead of a new circle with new color and position , the one that is already running is displayed .

The only way to have a new circle is to stop the live wallpaper by having a different one and then again starting the app.

what I am trying to have is to , each time I click on the icon a new live wallpaper is loaded without affecting the one already running and if i click the "set as live wallpaper" button the old one is replaced with the new one.

Android Launcher Class

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new CoreLWP(), config);
    }
}
```

Live Wallpaper class

```
public class LiveWallpaper  extends AndroidLiveWallpaperService {

public CoreLWP wallpaper;

@Override
public void onCreateApplication () {
    super.onCreateApplication();

    final AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    this.wallpaper = new CoreLWP();
    initialize(this.wallpaper, config);

 }
}
```

Core Live Wallpaper class

```
public class CoreLWP extends ApplicationAdapter implements ApplicationListener, AndroidWallpaperListener {


private ShapeRenderer ball;
private float x,y;
private Random random;

private float r,g,b;

@Override
public void create () {
    ball = new ShapeRenderer();
    random = new Random();

    //generating random position
    x = random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
    y = random.nextInt(Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

     //generating random rgb values
     r = getFloatRandomNum(0, 1) ;
     g = getFloatRandomNum(0, 1) ;
     b = getFloatRandomNum(0, 1) ;
}

@Override
public void render () {

    //setting the background
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //updating x and y position
    x = x + 0.5f;
    y = y + 0.6f;

    ball.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    ball.setColor(r,g,b,1);
    ball.circle(x,y,100);
    ball.end();

}

//returns a random float number between a range
private float getFloatRandomNum(float min, float max) {
    float random = min + new Random().nextFloat() * (max - min);
    return random;
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    ball.dispose();
}

@Override
public void offsetChange(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {}

@Override
public void previewStateChange(boolean isPreview) {}

@Override
public void iconDropped(int x, int y) {}
}
```

Comment: Android does not provide a callback for this. It is impossible to do as you described. You can check the preview state change, but you won't know if they chose "set wallpaper" or backed out of the chooser.

Comment: Is there any other way around this issue . If I add any preference setting to the live wallpaper and a user makes any changes to the preference . Then the change is reflected on the running live wallpaper without clicking the "set as wallpaper" button . Is there any way to stop this or Do I have to live it like this.

Comment: I can think of a possible way that is convoluted but why would you want it to behave unexpectedly? If a user changes a preference, they will expect the change to take place without further steps, just like in ever other app on the phone.

Comment: Much appreciated . The app is working fine except this issue . I just don't want the user to feel like its some kind of a bug . Otherwise everything is fine.

Comment: In my opinion, the behavior you say you want would seem like a bug because it is unexpected and not the way all other correctly-designed apps work.

Comment: Use this method that comes with the WallpaperListener:
`public void previewStateChange(boolean isPreview) {}
`
It will be called everytime you change between preview and running.
There you can reset your wallpaper in your code and voila, everything runs fine :)